# Add polygons to extruded 2D object

Tags: mesh

After watching so many tutorials I thought I could quickly pose a short question here. I want to add some topography to an extruded object which I imported from a 2D vector file. The problem is that in ordner to sculpt it I need to add some more polygons on the top face and on the sides. I know this could be done with the knife tool but I'm searching for a way to turn this into a nicely ordered grid. I've tried out the boolean intersect but did not advance this far enough.

How can I add more polygons to the red object?
Should I try to combine the top face with the grid on top and intersect the sides with the planes below?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Maribel

Example:
[image: Extruded 2D object with grid and planes]

Answer (score 8):

### version Remesh

If you want an even grid also on edges you can try to use modifier **Remesh** > *Sharps*

[image]

or *Blocks* modifier directly on Silhouethe object... just use Solidify modifier before Remesh to let it works.

[image]

### version Knife Project

Select Silhouette **than** Grid, go to *Top View*, switch to edit mode and search for **Knife Project**, but ...

[image]

... since silhouette use more vertices that grid you will have generated n-gons on edges that can be problematic for modifiers or modeling. You wil see :)

[image]

---

### Notes:

If you need a grid on sides, extrude it after Knife Project. You can use *Loop Cut* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for that.

For some generated terrain you can use *Displace* modifier with Cloud texture ... here used on version Remesh > Blocks > Octree Depth 9

[image]

Comment: For the _Knife Project_ option it's only important that the cutting object (the silhouette) is a flat plane, while in his screenshot it looks like it's an extruded object. But it doesn't matter if the silhouette is above or below the grid for cutting to work, it's just a matter of seeing the silhouette in _Solid View_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Right, doesn't matter if above or under ... edited :) But it doesn't has to be necessarily a flat plane - it can be curvy, and it can be extruded if there is not a bottom face. It just has to be "open" (non-manifold). I'm not sure what do you mean "Solid View". BTW it can be only silhouette without faces or more silhouettes above or what ever . What matters the most is point of view (since it is projection.

Comment: You're right, not necessarily a flat plane, but open... I just mentioned because the silhouette in the screenshot is extruded so I guess it has a bottom and following your answer it might throw an error without any obvious reason for him. With 'solid view' I mean putting silhouette on top isn't necessary for it to work but helps to see where you are cutting when in solid view and not x-ray or wireframe view.